# IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable. (when comparing int value row by row with dataframe's column entries)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I am currently getting the above mentioned `IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.`error. What i basically want to do is given a x-Value `xEnd`and a y-value `yEnd` to check if there is a row in my data frame `df` where its `x-column item == xEnd` and its `y-column item ==yEnd`. I thought it work well with the `.any()` function but somehow i get the above mentioned error. Could anyone explain me how I can fix it?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,1,1,2,2,2], 'y':[1,2,3,3,4,3]})
xEnd= 2
yEnd= 3

    if(((df['x'] == xEnd) and (df['y'] == yEnd)).any()):
        print("true")
    else:
        print("false")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure as to what you want to return but if you simply looking for this condition: `(df['x'] == xEnd) & (df['y'] == yEnd)` and want to return the rows that meet the condition then just do

```
df[(df['x'] == xEnd) & (df['y'] == yEnd)]
```

which selects values from a dataframe with boolean criterion.